# Redis creating a Set with expiry

Tags: redis

When I create a new Set (using `SADD`) I need to set the expiration for that Set.
Is there any way to create a Set key with expiry?

Note: I need to do that in one command, because my program checks if the set exists before going to update it - so if its existing with no expiration no update will occur.
My program runs on AWS so if I split it to 2 commands, only the creation can be executed without the expiration (happened to me in the past).
Thanks!

I couldn't find a way to set expiry on a Set other than using the `EXPIRE` command - risking in the program crashing before the `EXPIRE` command (i.e. AWS service restarting for any reason) and the Set existing with no expiration.

Edit: I found a work-around, when I can check if the `TTL` of the key is < 0 instead of `EXISTS`, so if the `EXPIRE` didn't work for some reason I will update the Set anyway. This can help but I prefer to also save traffic when expiring the Set, and send one command (i.e. `SADD` with expiry) instead of `SADD` and `EXPIRE`.

Comment: You can run the two commands in a Lua script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [transactions](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/)? For example:

```
multi
sadd key member1 member2 ...
expire key seconds
exec
```

It is guaranteed that the sadd and expire will be executed as a single unit on the node and on replicas if you use any. If you use [pipelining](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/) you don't need to do it in multiple rounds from the client so perf will have minimal / no impact.

Comment: As @TomerW suggests, transactions will work. You also might want to look into [scripts or functions](https://redis.io/commands/?group=scripting). These will execute atomically and with a single command.